# create a list with pairs from a column in pandas

Tags: python

I have a column with pairs like these

| id | pairs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c |
| 2 | b,d |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | d,e |
| 5 | g,h |
| 6 | a,h |
| 7 | f,d |
| 8 | o,p |

I want to have these output

```
[('ca', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),('b','c'),('b','d'),('d','e'),('g','h'),('a','h'),('f','d'),('o','p')]
```

I did these, but not the desired solution

```
for pair in combinations([df['pairs']], 2):
print(pairs)
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
pairs = []

for row in df['pairs']:
    row_list = row.split(',')
    for pair in combinations(row_list, 2):
        pairs.append(pair)

print(pairs)
```